# Unable to unlock screen pattern/pin lock on notification arrival in Android app

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-windowmanager

I am making an Android hybrid application in which my requirements are that as soon as a notification arrives, my app should open and disable all locks. I tried using `KeyguardManager(deprecated)` but it's working on some devices only. Basically below Lollipop only.

Now I am using this piece of code to achieve the desired result but all in vain.
I have seen many posts regarding the same issue everywhere. `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` is suggested as a replacement for `KeyguardManager`,
but this is not working for me.

```
((Activity) mContext).getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Flag dismisse full screen, flag show when local, flag dismisse anoymous input method

Irish of.

Is